# NSURLSession Downloading Many Files, How shall I update the metadata?

Tags: core-data, download, nsurlsession

I am building an app that downloads files and it keeps some metadata related to the file in core data.

I was very intrigued by the NSURLSession download task as it will allow me to download in the background and not have to write my own queueing mechanism.

My problem is when I get the callback 
`- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {`

What pattern or method should I use to update the associated metadata for this file after moving it to the application sandbox? Specifically, I need to set a property on the metadata that will tell the application that the file is already downloaded.

I had originally started down the path of adding a property to the download task via associated objects that will tell me the objectid of the core data object. but it started to seem very hacky and it seems like there should be a simpler method.

Does anyone have an idea? am I explaining the problem sufficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback contains the original `NSURL`. Store the URL as part of your metadata. When the download completes, fetch the metadata record for that URL and update it.